# Parquet Encryption: How to encrypt array of structs?

Tags: apache-spark, encryption, parquet

Since spark 3.2,
there is this interesting functionality from Parquet: [Parquet Columnar Encryption](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#columnar-encryption)

The documentation is pretty clear on how to specify which key to use for a specific column in the dataframe schema. I.e.:

> squaresDF.write.
> option("parquet.encryption.column.keys" , "keyA:square")

if we want to encrypt a column called `square` with a key indentified by `keyA` tag in our KMS system.

The problem is:
how to specify the column name if my column is an array of a Struct type ?

For example

```
myDF.printSchema

root
|-- int_column: integer (nullable = false)
|-- square_int_column: double (nullable = false)
|-- more: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I specify the key for the column `more` ? or for column `more.name` ? Is it supported ? I cannot find anything on the parquet or spark doc about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research,

I decided to explore a generated parquet file with parquet-tools in order to understand how arrays of struct are organised in the file.

So, after creating a parquet file with the needed schema, I opened it with:

```
 java ~/parquet-tools-1.11.0.jar meta <my-parquet-file-path> | less
```

Checking in the metadata of the columns, I found that:

```
[...cut...]
more:                               OPTIONAL F:1
.list:                              REPEATED F:1
..element:                          OPTIONAL F:8
...name:                            OPTIONAL BINARY L:STRING R:1 D:4
[...cut...]
```

So, to encrypt that, we need to specify the column as:

```
squaresDF.write
   .option("parquet.encryption.column.keys" , "keyA:more.list.element.name")
```

Comment: does this encryption allow rotation of keys ? @btbbass

Comment: Yes, check https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encryption.md for more information.